# How to best get daily SUM for minute-level data?

Tags: mysql

I have a data set consisting of minute-by-minute data. My goal is to return minute-by-minute records, and add calculations that create sums of a certain field for the past 24 hours, counting back from each minute record.

The query I have is the following:

```
SELECT main.recorded_at AS x, (SELECT SUM(precipitation) FROM data AS sub WHERE sub.host = main.host sub.recorded_at BETWEEN SUBTIME(main.recorded_at, '24:00:00') AND main.recorded_at) AS y FROM data AS main WHERE host = 'xxxx' ORDER BY x ASC;
```

Is there a more efficient way to write this query? I have tried, but failed, so far, using LEFT JOINS and different GROUP BYs.

When I explain this query, I get the following:

```
1   PRIMARY main    ref host    host    767 const   4038    100.00  Using where; Using filesort
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  sub ref host,recorded_at    host    767 const   4038    100.00  Using where
```

In total, the query takes about 200 seconds to run with 8000 records, getting slower all the time. My goal is to get the aggregate 24-hour precipitation for each result, and somehow in under 2 seconds.

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way? I'm open to suggestions for other avenues to get the same result. :)

Thanks!
~Mike

Comment: You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302916/sql-server-query-by-hour-over-multiple-days

Comment: This is not a grouping by hourly interval, as the referenced link suggests. This is an aggregation of 24-hour period in 1-minute intervals. The complexity here is that the aggregation period is different than the record intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, it looks like you can use `SUM` with `CASE` to achieve the same result without using the correlated subquery.

```
SELECT recorded_at AS x, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN recorded_at BETWEEN SUBTIME(recorded_at, '24:00:00') AND recorded_at 
             THEN precipitation END) As y
FROM data 
WHERE host = 'xxxx' 
GROUP BY recorded_at
ORDER BY x ASC;
```

---

While I'm not sure this would yield a better performance, I do think it would solve your issue using an `OUTER JOIN` with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT main.recorded_at AS x, 
   SUM(sub.precipitation) As y
FROM data main LEFT JOIN data sub ON 
    main.host = sub.host AND 
    sub.recorded_at BETWEEN SUBTIME(main.recorded_at, '24:00:00') AND main.recorded_at
WHERE main.host = 'xxxx' 
GROUP BY main.recorded_at
ORDER BY x ASC;
```

Comment: I tried this out, but am not getting summarized data. I'm trying to wrap my head around the logic here, but I think the problem is that the CASE is always looking at the current record, and thus only summing up a single record.

Comment: @mike.bronner -- see updates.  +1 to your question as I see the issues you're having.

Comment: Thanks! :) I have played with the LEFT JOIN like you posted as well, put it actually seems to be less performant than using the SUB-SELECT. There may be no good way to do this type of thing in a query, and may have to add an additional field and calculate the 24-hour aggregation when the record is inserted.